# My simple code of jQuery is not working. I get a blank page when I run it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I am new to javascript. I wrote a simple code of jQuery, but it is not working. I get a blank page when I run it. Can someone please help me

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js">
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
    <div id = "myElement">
    <input id = "click" type = "button" value = "Click">
    </div>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        function sayHello(){
            alert("Hello jQuery");
        }

    $("#click").bind("button",sayHello);

    });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: the script is wrapping the html

Answer (score 2):

you have html mark up in script element also you need to bind the event `click`

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js">
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id = "myElement">
            <input id = "click" type = "button" value = "Click"/>
        </div>
        <script type = "text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                function sayHello(){
                    alert("Hello jQuery");
                }

                //$("#click").bind("click", sayHello); // the event is called click not bind
                $("#click").on("click", sayHello); // on is the preferred way to register event handler

            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UPykl3J8hmKdh0vID7gE?p=preview)

Comment: @user2709885 also see the updates, use on instead of bind to register event handlers

Comment: I've changed my code a bit by employing an anonymous function. But my code doesn't seem to work well. Can you please have a look.http://plnkr.co/edit/fWoHk2ygMnjJLP9W51xn?p=preview

Comment: @user2709885 you missed a set of closing brackets `});` see http://plnkr.co/edit/PFcIlql3rbt1N9GovRXV?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing JS code with html elements. This is not how things work. Move the html elements out from your `script`, like this -

```
<div id = "myElement">
    <input id = "click" type = "button" value = "Click">
</div>

<script type = "text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        function sayHello(){
            alert("Hello jQuery");
        }

        $("#click").bind("click",sayHello);
    });
</script>
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TnhDh/).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've moved html elements out from my script. But still when I click the button, the function is not working.

Comment: @user2709885: Edit your question and include your changes, so that I can take a look.

Comment: @user2709885: [Check now](http://plnkr.co/edit/3zL47G?p=preview). You missed a pair of `})`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id = "myElement">
    <input id = "click" type = "button" value = "Click">
    </div>
```

It doesnt come inside scripts..it should be out of it..

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function()
    {
        function sayHello(){
            alert("Hello jQuery");
        }

    $("#click").bind("button",sayHello);

    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've moved html elements out from my script. But still when I click the button, the function is not working.